# jquery UI sortable: how can I change the appearance of the "placeholder" object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In the example given at http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder the placeholder is the orange box that appears when you drag any of the items.

This element can be tweaked using the `placeholder` option -- but it only lets you modify the class of the element as described here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#options

I would like to customize this element more, e.g. by supplying a function to the `placeholder` option in the same manner that one can supply a function to the `helper` option.

What would I need to change (e.g. in sortable.js) to do this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Looking at the source for ui.sortable.js (1.7.2), you can cheat and set the `placeholder` to an object with a `element` function and an `update` function. The `element` function is used to return the placeholder dom object and the `update` function allows you to do things like correct its size (you can check out the `_createPlaceholder` function inside sortable if you want to see what the default implementation does).

So for example, the following will create a list item with the word *test* inside as your placeholder (note that it returns the actual dom object (`[0]`) and not the jQuery object itself):

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    placeholder: {
        element: function(currentItem) {
            return $("<li><em>test</em></li>")[0];
        },
        update: function(container, p) {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

If I'm reading source correctly, the `element` function should be passed the current item (jQuery object) and `this` should point to the `sortable` itself (i.e. `$("#sortable")` in this instance). In `update` you're passed the "container" which is the object which holds all the options, & the element, etc & the `placeholder` itself.

**Please note that this is an undocumented hack**, so it would obviously be unsupported & may change with the next version of jQuery UI... but it still may be of use to you, given you were talking about editing `ui.sortable.js` directly anyway.

Comment: Beautiful; if you want to make sortable work when you want a fixed height for the items while dragging (due to huge items, for example), you can use (in the update function above): `container.refreshPositions();` and that fixes everything. Whoohoo!

Comment: I'm using this hack now to implement draggable icons that display as the DOM element they represent when dragged over the linked Sortable! Extra kudos for reading the source; I tried that and now I need meds.

Comment: I was having issues with sortables between tables and having the tables resize due to different number of columns so I used this solution, but instead used `return $('<tr><td colspan="999"></td></tr>')[0];` to fix the problem.

Comment: @Johannes With this code you can set the colspan related to the number of columns: `return $('<tr><td colspan="' + currentItem.children('td').length + '">&nbsp;</td></tr>')[0];`

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you. Is having the `update` function necessary or can it be omitted?

Answer (score 53):

A more hackish approach that I found: one can use the `start` option to modify the placeholder element, e.g. as follows

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function (e, ui) { 
      // modify ui.placeholder however you like
      ui.placeholder.html("I'm modifying the placeholder element!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know if something changed, but this worked for me while Alconja's did not.

Comment: I don't think this is hackish at all; the official documentation (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) shows `ui.placeholder` in the overview section and and the `start` callback in the events section. I'd say this is the officially supported way to do it.

Comment: Agreed, the function form described by the OP would be nice, but until that finds its way into the project I think this is the sanctioned way to achieve the objective.

Comment: Note: This method only updates the contents of the placeholder, it will not change the placeholder element itself (attributes/classes/...)  Alconja's method let's you have full control.

Comment: @ezwrighter If you call `ui.placeholder.html()`, sure. But `ui.placeholder` is the actual placeholder element. And you can do anything with it that you can with any other element, including styling it or adding content to it.