# How to add simple sortable placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I was hoping to get some help regarding how to create a placeholder. In my design, I have a bottom drawer that opens when the gray circle is clicked on. The drawer opens to reveal a list of items that can be dragged into the main lists above. What I am trying to create is a dotted placeholder that appears in the main list area (wherever you try to drag an item from the drawer). I would really, really appreciate any help! Here is a simple fiddle of my work: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs7bv59n/)

Below is my current JQuery for the Sortable function:

```
$(".connectable_list1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
});
$(".connectable_list2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150002/jquery-ui-sortable-how-can-i-change-the-appearance-of-the-placeholder-object

Comment: Thanks for the resource! I was able to figure it out.